# _TypeError - type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I got this error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Null' in get method flutter

API response from backend:

```json
{
    "ticketId": "5ea260c9-0b70-482d-b8ca-7f811a96bd29",
    "ticketNumber": 1524,
    "subject": "Subjet 112",
    "priority": "Low",
    "description": "Postman api post",
    "anyAttachment": false,
    "status": "Open",
    "createdAt": "2022-03-20T05:08:37.672Z",
    "requesterName": "Ayana Mohan",
    "requesterUUID": "90bf9452-b690-47f2-aa0c-4b3809fdb023",
    "requesterPhone": "1231423123",
    "requesterEmail": "testuser01@gmail.com",
    "customerId": "c8595a40-ea63-4883-9f94-e79f2545dee3",
    "ticketType": "Incident",
    "categoryId": null,
    "category": null,
    "assigneeUUID": null,
    "assigneeName": null,
    "assigneeEmail": null,
    "assigneePhone": null,
    "groupUUID": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "rcaTitle": null,
    "rca": null,
    "rcaSolution": null,
    "rcaWorkaround": null,
    "rcsSymptoms": null,
    "rcaBy": null,
    "rcaDate": null,
    "rcaTag": [],
    "formControl": [],
    "classified": null,
    "initiatedBy": null,
    "initiationComment": null,
    "impact": null,
    "risk": null,
    "downtimeStart": null,
    "downtimeEnd": null,
    "assetName": null,
    "serviceName": null,
    "applicationName": null,
    "submissionStatus": null,
    "planningStatus": null,
    "implementationStatus": null,
    "reviewStatus": null,
    "closeStatus": null,
    "finalStatus": null,
    "ticketView": null,
    "completeDate": null,
    "cabRequired": null,
    "rolloutPlan": null,
    "backoutPlan": null,
    "impactAnalysis": null,
    "reason": null,
    "workflowStatus": null,
    "releasePlan": null,
    "testComment": null,
    "testResult": null,
    "closeComment": null,
    "closeResult": null,
    "refTicketId": null,
    "tenantId": "8e963a4d-75d3-4727-b92d-44f24ef80aad"
}
```

This is the get API function that I use

```dart
 Future<List<UserTicketResponseModel>> getAllUserIssueTicket() async {
    List<UserTicketResponseModel> userTicketModel = [];
    final _token = await getToken();

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(ticketingBaseUrl + USER_TICKET),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $_token",
        },
      );

      userTicketLoading = true;
      var userTickets = jsonDecode(response.body);
      userTicketModel = userTickets
          .map((tickets) => UserTicketResponseModel.fromJson(tickets))
          .toList();
      notifyListeners();
      return userTicketModel;
    } on SocketException {
      throw 'No Internet Connection';
    }
  }
```

**Model Class:**

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

UserTicketResponseModel userTicketResponseModelFromJson(String str) =>
    UserTicketResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userTicketResponseModelToJson(UserTicketResponseModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserTicketResponseModel {
  UserTicketResponseModel({
    required this.ticketId,
    required this.ticketNumber,
    required this.subject,
    required this.priority,
    required this.description,
    required this.anyAttachment,
    required this.status,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.requesterName,
    required this.requesterUuid,
    required this.requesterPhone,
    required this.requesterEmail,
    required this.customerId,
    required this.ticketType,
    required this.categoryId,
    required this.category,
    required this.assigneeUuid,
    required this.assigneeName,
    required this.assigneeEmail,
    required this.assigneePhone,
    required this.groupUuid,
    required this.groupName,
    required this.rcaTitle,
    required this.rca,
    required this.rcaSolution,
    required this.rcaWorkaround,
    required this.rcsSymptoms,
    required this.rcaBy,
    required this.rcaDate,
    required this.rcaTag,
    required this.formControl,
    required this.classified,
    required this.initiatedBy,
    required this.initiationComment,
    required this.impact,
    required this.risk,
    required this.downtimeStart,
    required this.downtimeEnd,
    required this.assetName,
    required this.serviceName,
    required this.applicationName,
    required this.submissionStatus,
    required this.planningStatus,
    required this.implementationStatus,
    required this.reviewStatus,
    required this.closeStatus,
    required this.finalStatus,
    required this.ticketView,
    required this.completeDate,
    required this.cabRequired,
    required this.rolloutPlan,
    required this.backoutPlan,
    required this.impactAnalysis,
    required this.reason,
    required this.workflowStatus,
    required this.releasePlan,
    required this.testComment,
    required this.testResult,
    required this.closeComment,
    required this.closeResult,
    required this.refTicketId,
    required this.tenantId,
  });

  String ticketId;
  int ticketNumber;
  String subject;
  String priority;
  String description;
  bool anyAttachment;
  String status;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String requesterName;
  String requesterUuid;
  String requesterPhone;
  String requesterEmail;
  String customerId;
  String ticketType;
  dynamic categoryId;
  dynamic category;
  dynamic assigneeUuid;
  dynamic assigneeName;
  dynamic assigneeEmail;
  dynamic assigneePhone;
  dynamic groupUuid;
  dynamic groupName;
  dynamic rcaTitle;
  dynamic rca;
  dynamic rcaSolution;
  dynamic rcaWorkaround;
  dynamic rcsSymptoms;
  dynamic rcaBy;
  dynamic rcaDate;
  List<dynamic> rcaTag;
  dynamic formControl;
  dynamic classified;
  dynamic initiatedBy;
  dynamic initiationComment;
  dynamic impact;
  dynamic risk;
  dynamic downtimeStart;
  dynamic downtimeEnd;
  dynamic assetName;
  dynamic serviceName;
  dynamic applicationName;
  dynamic submissionStatus;
  dynamic planningStatus;
  dynamic implementationStatus;
  dynamic reviewStatus;
  dynamic closeStatus;
  dynamic finalStatus;
  dynamic ticketView;
  dynamic completeDate;
  dynamic cabRequired;
  dynamic rolloutPlan;
  dynamic backoutPlan;
  dynamic impactAnalysis;
  dynamic reason;
  dynamic workflowStatus;
  dynamic releasePlan;
  dynamic testComment;
  dynamic testResult;
  dynamic closeComment;
  dynamic closeResult;
  dynamic refTicketId;
  String tenantId;

  factory UserTicketResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      UserTicketResponseModel(
        ticketId: json["ticketId"],
        ticketNumber: json["ticketNumber"],
        subject: json["subject"],
        priority: json["priority"],
        description: json["description"],
        anyAttachment: json["anyAttachment"],
        status: json["status"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        requesterName: json["requesterName"],
        requesterUuid: json["requesterUUID"],
        requesterPhone: json["requesterPhone"],
        requesterEmail: json["requesterEmail"],
        customerId: json["customerId"],
        ticketType: json["ticketType"],
        categoryId: json["categoryId"],
        category: json["category"],
        assigneeUuid: json["assigneeUUID"],
        assigneeName: json["assigneeName"],
        assigneeEmail: json["assigneeEmail"],
        assigneePhone: json["assigneePhone"],
        groupUuid: json["groupUUID"],
        groupName: json["groupName"],
        rcaTitle: json["rcaTitle"],
        rca: json["rca"],
        rcaSolution: json["rcaSolution"],
        rcaWorkaround: json["rcaWorkaround"],
        rcsSymptoms: json["rcsSymptoms"],
        rcaBy: json["rcaBy"],
        rcaDate: json["rcaDate"],
        rcaTag: List<dynamic>.from(json["rcaTag"].map((x) => x)),
        formControl: json["formControl"],
        classified: json["classified"],
        initiatedBy: json["initiatedBy"],
        initiationComment: json["initiationComment"],
        impact: json["impact"],
        risk: json["risk"],
        downtimeStart: json["downtimeStart"],
        downtimeEnd: json["downtimeEnd"],
        assetName: json["assetName"],
        serviceName: json["serviceName"],
        applicationName: json["applicationName"],
        submissionStatus: json["submissionStatus"],
        planningStatus: json["planningStatus"],
        implementationStatus: json["implementationStatus"],
        reviewStatus: json["reviewStatus"],
        closeStatus: json["closeStatus"],
        finalStatus: json["finalStatus"],
        ticketView: json["ticketView"],
        completeDate: json["completeDate"],
        cabRequired: json["cabRequired"],
        rolloutPlan: json["rolloutPlan"],
        backoutPlan: json["backoutPlan"],
        impactAnalysis: json["impactAnalysis"],
        reason: json["reason"],
        workflowStatus: json["workflowStatus"],
        releasePlan: json["releasePlan"],
        testComment: json["testComment"],
        testResult: json["testResult"],
        closeComment: json["closeComment"],
        closeResult: json["closeResult"],
        refTicketId: json["refTicketId"],
        tenantId: json["tenantId"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "ticketId": ticketId,
        "ticketNumber": ticketNumber,
        "subject": subject,
        "priority": priority,
        "description": description,
        "anyAttachment": anyAttachment,
        "status": status,
        "createdAt": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "requesterName": requesterName,
        "requesterUUID": requesterUuid,
        "requesterPhone": requesterPhone,
        "requesterEmail": requesterEmail,
        "customerId": customerId,
        "ticketType": ticketType,
        "categoryId": categoryId,
        "category": category,
        "assigneeUUID": assigneeUuid,
        "assigneeName": assigneeName,
        "assigneeEmail": assigneeEmail,
        "assigneePhone": assigneePhone,
        "groupUUID": groupUuid,
        "groupName": groupName,
        "rcaTitle": rcaTitle,
        "rca": rca,
        "rcaSolution": rcaSolution,
        "rcaWorkaround": rcaWorkaround,
        "rcsSymptoms": rcsSymptoms,
        "rcaBy": rcaBy,
        "rcaDate": rcaDate,
        "rcaTag": List<dynamic>.from(rcaTag.map((x) => x)),
        "formControl": formControl,
        "classified": classified,
        "initiatedBy": initiatedBy,
        "initiationComment": initiationComment,
        "impact": impact,
        "risk": risk,
        "downtimeStart": downtimeStart,
        "downtimeEnd": downtimeEnd,
        "assetName": assetName,
        "serviceName": serviceName,
        "applicationName": applicationName,
        "submissionStatus": submissionStatus,
        "planningStatus": planningStatus,
        "implementationStatus": implementationStatus,
        "reviewStatus": reviewStatus,
        "closeStatus": closeStatus,
        "finalStatus": finalStatus,
        "ticketView": ticketView,
        "completeDate": completeDate,
        "cabRequired": cabRequired,
        "rolloutPlan": rolloutPlan,
        "backoutPlan": backoutPlan,
        "impactAnalysis": impactAnalysis,
        "reason": reason,
        "workflowStatus": workflowStatus,
        "releasePlan": releasePlan,
        "testComment": testComment,
        "testResult": testResult,
        "closeComment": closeComment,
        "closeResult": closeResult,
        "refTicketId": refTicketId,
        "tenantId": tenantId,
      };
}
```

This is my listen function:

```
List<UserTicketResponseModel> _userTicketModel = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserTickets();
}

Future<void> getUserTickets() async {
    UserTicketProvider provider =
        Provider.of<UserTicketProvider>(context, listen: false);
    _userTicketModel = await provider.getAllUserIssueTicket();
    print("User Tickets Main: " + _userTicketModel.toString());
  }


body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _userTicketModel.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: UserTicketsList(
              ticketNumber: _userTicketModel[index].ticketNumber.toString(),
              requester: _userTicketModel[index].requesterName.toString(),
             
              subject: _userTicketModel[index].subject.toString(),
              priorityType: _userTicketModel[index].priority.toString(),
              statusType: _userTicketModel[index].status.toString(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

When I run the app, in model class Exception occurred and showed this error:

> _TypeError type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I'm a beginner and I don't understand what the problem is! I tried model class null check with `??` or as `String?` but not working!

Comment: The problem is that some of the fields on your JSON response have `null` values and you try to serialize them in a `String`. Either declare your  variables nullable, e.g `String? requesterName;` or give a default value if null, e.g `requesterName: json["requesterName"] ?? 'Requester name was null`,

Comment: after adding ?? "null" each model and i changed to response.body as List variable and when i print value it showing [Instance of 'UserTicketResponseModel', Instance of 'UserTicketResponseModel', .. what should i do?